# How to cUrl a DELETE request to Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a small JSON api which I'm building in Yesod. In order to test the API I am using cUrl. However, the following request returns `405 method not allowed`:

`curl -X DELETE -H "X-User-Name: $name" -H "X-User-Token: $token" -H "accept:application/json" http://localhost:3000/login`

The routes file definitely contains `DELETE` as a method on the login route. I am using `defaultYesodMiddleware`.

Here is the handler:

```
-- ^ Invalidate the user token
deleteLoginR :: Handler Aeson.Value
deleteLoginR = authenticateUser >>= \u ->
               let newU = u { DS.token = "" } in
               DS.saveEntity newU >>= \case
                Left e -> sendResponseStatus status500 (cs e :: Text)
                Right _ -> sendResponseStatus status200 ("Logged out" :: Text)
```

here is the `authenticateUser` function:

```
{-| Check that a user is properly logged in using the authentication headers -}
authenticateUser :: Handler User
authenticateUser = lookupHeader "X-User-Name" >>= \case 
                    Nothing ->
                      sendResponseStatus status406 ("X-User-Name not set" :: Text)
                    Just name ->
                      lookupHeader "X-User-Token" >>= \case
                        Nothing ->
                          sendResponseStatus status406 ("X-User-Token not set" :: Text)
                        Just token ->
                          (DS.loadEntities ["User"] constraints Nothing :: Handler (Either Text [User])) 
                          >>= \case 
                            Left e -> sendResponseStatus status500 (cs e :: Text)
                            Right records -> pure $ List.head records
                          where constraints = [ Where ("name", Equals, cs name)
                                              , Where ("token", Equals, cs token)
                                              ]
```

and the route declaration:

`/login LoginR GET POST PATCH DELETE`

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: sending delete request to `http://localhost:3000/login` doesn't seem reasonable. Are you sure you have this route defined? Probably you meant to send delete to something like `http://localhost:3000/logout`?

Comment: Maybe you're right about the semantics, but the route definitely exists.

Comment: You'll most likely need to provide source code for anyone to find the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! It was some kind of caching issue in stack, where it had cached an old version of the routes file. Killing `yesod devel` and running `stack build --force-dirty` fixed it.